# edmx file to an XML document

Tags: xml, linq-to-entities, edmx

Can I connect an edmx to an xml document instead of a sql database.If so how can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not unless you write an EF provider for it. But there is [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).

You're unlikely to get a really good solution to your problem if you don't mention what the underlying problem is.